# Movie about people waking up in a locked warehouse without remembering who's a good or a bad guy

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this really good movie where there is a group of people who slowly wake up (I think it was after a gas leak) in a locked warehouse. Nobody remembers anything.

Then they get a call from somebody telling them that the robbery was successfull and that they are coming back. After this they realize that some of them are hostages and the others are with the robbers and they try to figure out who is who, before the robbers come back.

I'd really like to see this movie again but I cannot remember the name.
It's not [this movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41087/movie-about-a-group-of-people-waking-up-in-a-room-knowing-that-one-or-more-of-t).

I saw it at the cinema about 10 years ago and the movie was American. I can't remember the actors but I think there was no movie star involved in the cast.

Comment: I have seen remake of this movie few days back "acid factory" but its in hindi

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like [Unknown](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0450340/combined) from 2006 with Jim Caviezel, Greg Kinnear, Bridget Moynahan & Joe Pantoliano.

> Five men wake up in a locked-down warehouse with no memory of who they are. They are forced to figure out who is good and who is bad to stay alive.

They get a phone call at some point and it turns out that some of them were kidnapped for ransom. Here's the trailer:

Comment: I think that's it! I must watch it to make sure but the surroundings and the atmosphere look the same! Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Apparently, there was also an [unofficial Indian remake in 2009](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201557/combined).

Comment: If there is no dancing involved, I will watch that too :P

Comment: @papakias But if there is no dancing, how will the hero and heroine express their love in the middle of a tense action scene?

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari hahaha ok! Accepted!

Comment: Not the same movie, but if you like this, you might also like Dark Matter. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4159076/

Comment: @JonSG And that in turn reminds me of the TNG episode [Conundrum](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Conundrum_(episode))

Comment: @JonSG Dark matter which reminds me of Pandorum http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1188729/